# EF Core, include derived type property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-database-first

I have a small problem with a specific `include` statement.
My datastructure is as follows:

```
[Table("item")]
public class Item
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string ItemCode { get; set; }
  ...
}

public abstract class DerivedItemAbstractBase : Item
{
  [ForeignKey("ItemId")]
  public List<Assignment> Assignments { get; set; }
  ...
}

[Table("item")]
public class DerivedItemA : DerivedItemAbstractBase
{
  ...
}

[Table("item")]
public class DerivedItemB : DerivedItemAbstractBase
{
  ...
}

public class ItemContext : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

Now I want to get a list of all `DerivedItemA` and include properties of it.
I have the following method:

```
public List<DerivedItemA> GetDerivedItemsA()
{
  var list = _context.Items
             .Include(x => (x as DerivedItemA).Assignments)
             .ToList();
}
```

This code compiles just fine and is something I have found on stackoverflow.
However executing this results in an exception with the short message `Invalid include`.
I dont know how to solve this problem.
The project is a database-first approach so I have no control over the database.
All items are stored in the same table `item`.
I cannot create multiple `DbSets` because there is no discriminator column in the table and I
cannot configure a custom discriminator in code because it would need to discriminate based on multiple properties and not a single property.

Is there any other way of doing this?
Currently I am solving it by iterating through all `ItemContext.Items` then doing a `.Select()` on each and creating a `new DerivedItemA`. After that I manually set every `Assignment` by iterating from the `Assignment` table.
However this approach takes far too long and it would be a lot quicker if I could just include it in the initial query.